# How to access nested values from json api response in React-admin?

Tags: react-admin

The API endpoint returns the following json when a front end user visits the http://localhost:3000/#/org/ou-cb2 edit page:

```
{"orgid":"ou-cb2",
"recordtype":"aws_org",
"arn":"arn:aws:organizations::999999999999:ou/o-gh/ou-cb2",
"orgnamefriendly":"Developer Accounts",
"parentid":"ou-5j",
"lastModified":{"$date":1646327467888},
"id":"ou-cb2",
"contacts":[
{"name":"BossLady Lynda","email":"lynda@gmail.com","alertoptin":"False","billingoptin":"False","orgtechcontact":"False","orgbillingcontact":"True"}, 
{"name":"BossGuy Jim","email":"jim@gmail.com","alertoptin":"False","billingoptin":"False","orgtechcontact":"False","orgbillingcontact":"True"}
]
}
```

My App.js looks like the following:

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin dashboard={Dashboard} dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider} title="Placeholder">
      <Resource name="org" list={OrgList} edit={OrgEdit} create={OrgCreate} icon={PostIcon}/>
  </Admin>
);
```

My Orgs.js looks like the following:

```
export const OrgEdit = () => (
    <Edit title='{<OrgTitle Placeholder />}'>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput disabled source="orgid" />
        <TextInput disabled source="arn" />
        <TextInput source="orgnamefriendly" />
        <TextInput disabled source="parentid" />
        <TextInput source="contacts" />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
);
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to view and edit the nested values for contacts.

Bonus... the list of contacts will have some default keys but it may also have a few dynamic key/value pairs. Can I use  for part of an api response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-admin provides the `<ArrayField>` and `<ArrayInput>` components to visualize and edit nested arrays:

```
export const OrgEdit = () => (
    <Edit title='{<OrgTitle Placeholder />}'>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput disabled source="orgid" />
            <TextInput disabled source="arn" />
            <TextInput source="orgnamefriendly" />
            <TextInput disabled source="parentid" />
            <ArrayInput source="contacts">
                <SimpleFormIterator>
                    <TextInput source="name" />
                    <TextInput source="email" />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Check the Documentation at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ArrayField.html and https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ArrayInput.html

Comment: Thank you, this example and the documentation is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!